# Different behavior NodeJS in foreground and background launch

Tags: javascript, node.js

I created an app using NodeJS. In the app i have the next code:

```
(async () => {
 const logincaptcha = await askUser();
})();
```

askUser function based on setTimeout utilization

```
async function askUser() {
console.log('Here we are askUser');
return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
     var timerId = setInterval(() => {
        if (userAnswer  !== "") {
            console.log('Here is our answer ' + userAnswer);
            clearInterval(timerId);
            resolve(userAnswer);
    }
        else {console.log('Please enter something');}
    },2000);
})}
```

When I start the app using "npm start" - is ok, all works as expected.
If I start the app and put it in the background "npm start &" this code doesn't work at all. 
I am confused and looking how to handle it.
Does anyone have thoughts?

Comment: The script you posted seems to work fine. What does `jobs` output?